# Vite + TailwindCSS : :focus is not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm creating a react app with vite and tailwind.

I want to use `:focus` but it's not working. This is the code :

```js
<button
onClick={dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOG_MODAL', payload: 'in' })}
className="focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline py-2 px-4 mr-1 rounded bg-gray-100 text-black">
    Connexion
</button>
```

Here is my tailwind config file :

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'man': '/img/man.jpg'
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      boxShadow: ["hover", "focus", "active"]
    }
  }, 
  plugins: [],
}
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Comment: can you include vite.config ?

Comment: I added vite.config.js

Comment: it was just shadow-outline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TailwindCSS doesn’t offer a `shadow-outline` class by default.

[TailwindCSS Docs on Box-Shadow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow)

You can create the extra class by adding it to your `tailwind.config.js`

I import the default theme, because I don’t think you’ll want to replace all the default box-shadow styles.

```
// tailwind.config.js
const { boxShadow } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  ...,
  theme: {
    boxShadow: {
      ...boxShadow,
      outline: 'shadow-style-here'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was that. I didn't pay attention shadow-outline was replaced by ring in tailwind v2